# pandas error in dropping column with complex column name

Tags: python, pandas

For practical reasons I need to define my column name with complex tuples. The problem is that I cannot drop the column as usual as a result. To replicate my problem,

```
complex_column_name = (u'CHRIS/CME_SP1', 34, ((u'CHRIS/CME_SP1_Settle_rolling_200_mean_to_current_value', 1),))

pd_tmp = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,1),columns=[complex_column_name])

pd_tmp.drop(complex_column_name,axis=1)
```

The error is :

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

Any help? Thank you.

Comment: Read the doc [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas-dataframe-drop).you need to specify it's `columns` or `axis=1`

Comment: I added axis = 1, it is not useful... I actually gave up... I convert every tuple into str, and use an external dictionary to keep track of everything....

Comment: Did you add `[]`?

Comment: not useful also....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats not an efficient way of setting column name so instead use a boolean mask and select the columns rather than dropping it i.e

```
mask = pd_tmp.columns != complex_column_name
ndf = pd_tmp.iloc[:,mask]
```

Answer (score 1):

After replicating your code I get following messages.

```
...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    480 
    481     """
--> 482     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    483 
    484 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

According to [`numpy.asarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html)

> Input data, in any form that can be converted to an array. This
>   includes lists, lists of tuples, tuples, tuples of tuples, tuples of
>   lists and ndarrays.

The `complex_column_name` here is a complex sequence which is not included above.
My suggestion is to make your `complex_column_name` simpler.
Hope this could be helpful.